# SQL JOIN returning too many rows

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

I have three tables: `category`, `offers`, and `galleries`. In my application, I have a search box into which the user enters a `category-id`, and in every offer there can be up to 4 images.

I'm using the following SQL:

```
SELECT offers.id
      ,offers.description
      ,offers.min_bid
      ,offers.max_bid
      ,offers.status
      ,offers.ending_date
      ,galleries.image
      ,galleries.crop
FROM offers 
INNER JOIN galleries ON offers.id = galleries.offer_id 
WHERE cat_id = $id and offers.status = 1
```

The problem with the query is that it returns the same offer 4 times with different images each time... what I need, though, is for the offer to return just once, with the first image in the row - ignoring all of the other images associated with the same offer.

Can someone please help me figure out what to change about my SQL to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `group by offer limit 4` clause

Comment: yes ur idea helped me

Comment: i just added in the above query "group by offers.id"

Comment: Pls don't change your question according to the answer. Otherwise noone will know what was the issue.

Comment: yeah got you but i shared the answer that how i solved that

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` returns every row that satisfy the ON condition from both table. In this situation you may use `OUTER JOIN` which is `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Or you may also aggregate the result using `GROUP BY` as @cjg implied, but aggregating is more expensive than using `LEFT JOIN`.